# Is this Homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Let X be the subspace $(-\infty , -1)$ $\bigcup$ $[0 , \infty)$ of $R$. Show that the function $f:X \longrightarrow R$ defined by $f(x) = x+1$  if $x <-1$ and $f(x) = x$  if $x \geq 0$ is order preserving and surjective. Is this Homeomorphic?

It is very much obvious that the function is not Homeomorphic. But we know one sufficient condition -  If $X$ and $Y$ are ordered set in the order topology  and $g:X\rightarrow Y$ is order preserving and surjective, then $g$ is a homeomorphism.

I can not understand Where the function $f$ is violating this sufficient condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that the subspace topology on $(-\infty,-1)\bigcup [0,\infty)$ is *not* the same as the order topology. Indeed, $[0,1)$ is open in the subspace topology but not in the order topology, because any interval containing $0$ in the set $(-\infty,-1)\bigcup [0,\infty)$ must be of the form $\{x\in X\mid a<x<b \}$ with $a<-1$ and $0<b$, so it must also contain some points in $(-\infty,-1)$.

Thus if you give to $X$ the ordered topology, then any neighborhood of $0$ must also contain points in $(-\infty,-1)$, exactly as in $\Bbb R$; in that case, your $f$ is indeed an homeomorphism. The subspace topology, however, has more open sets, some of which are not preserved by $f$, which is thus not an homeo for that topology.

See also the relevant section in the [Wikipedia article on the order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Induced_order_topology).